# How a domain name pointer in a message works to point to the domain name in a DNS packet?

Tags: dns, wireshark

So I've installed Wireshark recently to figure out how a DNS packet looks like and I read the RFC-1034 and RFC-1035. Until now, the only thing that bothers me to find is how a domain name pointer in answer/answers section is used to point the domain name in queries section.

For a deep understanding in what I'm asking:

[image]

I've understanded that the first hexa value (c0) allows a pointer to be distinguished
from a label, but how the next value (3a) is supposed to point me to the actual domain name in this packet?

Comment: Why does this have a C# tag?  Why does this have a .net tag?

Comment: You are right. The question is unrelated to tags.

Comment: @Wyck This should not be there at all, no matter the tags, as it as nothing to do with programming at this stage.

Comment: You need to look at section 4.1.4 of RFC1035. The offset is a 2 octets sequence. The first two bits are 1 and you have to ignore them to compute the value. so `c0 3a` is offset value 3a in fact (as c0 base 16 is 11000000 base 2, so no bits needed to compute the real offset, but it won't necessarily always be `c0` as first byte, it can be any value higher than that, and then those bits will need to be used for the offset), so 58 bytes from the start of the message.

Comment: Ok, but can you please tell me which is the first byte of the message? I'm a bit confused now.

Comment: Is 58 counted from the first byte in DNS representation which is actually the transaction ID?

Comment: Again, 4.1.4 of RFC 1035: "The OFFSET field specifies an offset from
the start of the message (i.e., the first octet of the ID field in the
domain header).  A zero offset specifies the first byte of the ID field,
etc.
".  "ID" is what whiteshark shows at "Transaction ID" on top. This is basically the first element of the DNS packet.